# Сalculating the sum for the previous month in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I want to calculate sales for the previous month, but the data is the same as for the year.I used the formula CALCULATE(sum(Turnovers_by_position_2022[sales]), DATEADD(tblCalendar2022[Date],-1,MONTH)). There is a separate complete calendar table and is linked. Help me understand how to find sales for the previous month in this case.
Also this formula doesn't work:
CALCULATE (SUM ('Turnovers_by_position_2022'[sales]), FILTER (ALL ('tblCalendar2022'),
'tblCalendar2022'[Date]= DATE (YEAR ( TODAY ()), -1 , DAY( TODAY() ))))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEb3C.jpg)

Comment: What does your measure look like for `Last year` and `This year`? What's the date range in your `tblCalendar2022` table? And do you have any filters/slicer on your calendar table ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't have any date filters/slicers on the table visual. So `DATEADD(tblCalendar2022[Date],-1,MONTH)` is shifting all the dates in your `tblCalendar2022` back a month, and not to just the whole previous month.

Try the following:

```
Previous Month Today = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(Turnovers_by_position_2022[sales]), 
    PREVIOUSMONTH(tblCalendar2022[Date]),
    tblCalendar2022[Date] >= TODAY() 
  )
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?